# jquery Mobile 1.4.1 toggle header but keep a bar fixed

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I am trying to make the div with ui-bar fixed like we have the option to keep the header toolbar fixed .
I want to keep the uibar fixed when the header is toggled but I am not able to achieve this

Comment: Please add your code and explain more. You want to be fixed or hide on tap?

Comment: Like we have the fixed header and footer in here http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/toolbar-fixed/. I have one more bar below header .... and that bar should remain fixed even when the header goes on or off

Comment: Then you have two fixed headers, one with `data-tap-toggle=true` and and one without.

Comment: okay! I never tried 2 divs with header attribute... Lemme try this.

Comment: It didn't help http://jsfiddle.net/ZCEW2/2/ The fixed header is going above the real header in position

Answer (score 0):

You need to create two *header* divs, the first one should be *fixed* `data-position="fixed"` and activated to be hidden once body receives `tap` event `data-fullscreen="true"`.

```
<div data-role="header" data-fullscreen="true" data-position="fixed">
 <h1>Fixed Header</h1>
</div>
```

The second one a normal (not fixed) *header*.

```
<div data-role="header">
 <h1>Floating Header</h1>
</div>
```

On `pagecontainershow`, place *second* header underneath *fixed* header. Use `.one()` not `.on()` as you need to set *second* header's position once only.

Moreover, you also need to push *content*'s div down in order not to overlap with *second* header, by changing `margin-top` value.

```
$(document).one("pagecontainershow", function () {
  var fixed = $(".ui-header-fixed").outerHeight() - 1;
  $(".ui-header:eq(1)").css("top", fixed);
  $(".ui-content").css("margin-top", fixed);
});
```

Later, you need to reposition *second* header when *fixed* one is visible or hidden by listening to **Animation** events `animationend webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend MSAnimationEnd`.

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", function () {
    $(".ui-header-fixed").on("animationend webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend MSAnimationEnd", function (e) {
        var fixed = $(this).outerHeight() + $(this).offset().top;
        $(".ui-header:eq(1)").css("top", fixed);
        $(".ui-content").css("margin-top", fixed);
    });
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/Kuca6/)**